# Change QHeaderView data

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qheaderview

I try to modify the text of my QHeaderView (Horizontal) in my QTableWidget.

First question: Is it possible to set it editable like a QTableWidgetItem ?

Second question: If it's not possible, how can I do that, I tried to repaint it like this:

```
void EditableHeaderView::paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const
{
    painter->save();
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
    painter->restore();

    painter->setPen(Qt::SolidLine);
    painter->drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter, m_sValues[logicalIndex]);
}
```

But the header index is painted behind my text.

---

Another solution that I tried is:

```
void EditableHeaderView::mySectionDoubleClicked( int section )
{
    if (section != -1) // Not on a section
        m_sValues[section] = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Enter a value"), tr("Enter a value"), QLineEdit::Normal, "");

    QAbstractItemModel* model = this->model();
    model->setHeaderData(section, this->orientation(), m_sValues[section]);
    this->setModel(model);
}
```

But that doesn't works...

I hope someone have a solution.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

It can be done without subclassing, also you don't need paint your section to set text, do this with `setHeaderData`. For example next code works without errors.

```
//somewhere in constructor for example
connect(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader(),&QHeaderView::sectionDoubleClicked,[=]( int logicalIndex) {//with lambda
    qDebug() << "works";
    QString txt =  QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Enter a value"), tr("Enter a value"), QLineEdit::Normal, "");
    ui->tableWidget->model()->setHeaderData(logicalIndex,Qt::Horizontal,txt);
});
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The qDebug() works but my header text stay the same, I have copy paste your code and I don't understand why it doesn't works :'(

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why your solution doesn't works but I found a very simple workaround:

```
QString res =  QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Enter a value"), tr("Enter a value"), QLineEdit::Normal, "");
setHorizontalHeaderItem(logicalIndex, new QTableWidgetItem(res));
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: It is good that you found and shared answer, +1 for you. I didn't use this in my answer earlier because this will not work with QTableView, I wanted be more general, but it is good that this solution is suitable for you. Good luck :)