# How to make QHeaderView editable like data in cells?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview, qheaderview

I'm using a QAbstractTableModel to edit a panda dataframe. Editing the contents of the table was easy but i can't find the way to rename columns and rows inplace(like the rest of the data in the table). How I can do that?

Comment: Can you add some code or images to your question so we can see what stage you are at currently and what lines edits may need to be made

Comment: i use almost exactly [this](https://github.com/rominf/pandas/blob/4c2bbdbc0a57936eaebebd13b924f47270fa0661/pandas/sandbox/qtpandas.py) QAbstractTableModel

Comment: I answered earlier on similar question, but with c++, also it is another approach to edit data in header, but maybe it will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719640/change-qheaderview-data/26719997